# In my Kafka producer, Even after setting 'offset.metadata.max.bytes' to 0, it is not throwing OffsetMetadataTooLarge exception

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand 'OffsetMetadataTooLarge' exception. As per the below documentation, it should throw this exception when the client has tried to save its offset with associated metadata larger than the maximum size allowed by the server.

http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/OffsetMetadataTooLarge.html

To re-create this exception, i set 'offset.metadata.max.bytes' to 0 and sent a message but it didn't throw an exception.

Here is the docker-compose file for the broker and the docker console output.

```
  broker0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: broker0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9051:9051"
      - "9001:9001"
      - "9997:9997"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker0:9001,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9051
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 2
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_AUTO_LEADER_REBALANCE_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_OFFSET_METADATA_MAX_BYTES: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9997
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9997'
```

Here is the docker output

```
broker0_1          | ALLOW_UNSIGNED=false
broker0_1          | COMPONENT=kafka
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION=1
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_MAJOR_VERSION=5
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_MINOR_VERSION=3
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_MVN_LABEL=
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_PATCH_VERSION=1
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL=
broker0_1          | CONFLUENT_VERSION=5.3.1
broker0_1          | CUB_CLASSPATH=/etc/confluent/docker/docker-utils.jar
broker0_1          | HOME=/root
broker0_1          | HOSTNAME=broker0
broker0_1          | KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://broker0:9001,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9051
broker0_1          | KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
broker0_1          | KAFKA_AUTO_LEADER_REBALANCE_ENABLE=true
broker0_1          | KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
broker0_1          | KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
broker0_1          | KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS=0
broker0_1          | KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
broker0_1          | KAFKA_JMX_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9997
broker0_1          | KAFKA_JMX_PORT=9997
broker0_1          | KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
broker0_1          | KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
broker0_1          | KAFKA_OFFSET_METADATA_MAX_BYTES=0
broker0_1          | KAFKA_VERSION=5.3.1
broker0_1          | KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
broker0_1          | LANG=C.UTF-8
broker0_1          | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
broker0_1          | PWD=/
broker0_1          | PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=8.1.2
broker0_1          | PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.9-1
broker0_1          | SCALA_VERSION=2.12
broker0_1          | SHLVL=1
broker0_1          | ZULU_OPENJDK_VERSION=8=8.38.0.13
broker0_1          | _=/usr/bin/env
```

Can someone help me what am i missing here to re-create the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old topic, just for helping others reaching here, let me explain why the question is not right.

What is that property for? According the doumentation (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#offset-metadata-max-bytes): The maximum size for a metadata entry associated with an offset commit

The important part here is "associated with an offset commit". And an offset commit is related to a consumer, not to a producer. The commit allows Kafka to mark where in the queue a consumer is getting messages, and the metadata is associated to a certain commit (commits are stored in a Kafka topic called "__consumer_offsets").
That's why you don't get any exception, because your trying to force the exception when producing new messages instead of consuming a message.

Evenmore, if you consume messages with the autocommit parmeter setted to true, no metadata is stored at all, so you'll never get that exception. For that you should call commit method manually and fill the "OffsetAndMetadata" parameter. Thus, you can do that with the console consumer, you should program some code to do that (in Python, Java, Scala...)

Hope this helps.